# Here API | MultiValueQueryParameter for Via Points

Tags: here-api

I'm using the latest version of the **here javascript sdk 3.1.32.0**

When I use `H.service.Url.MultiValueQueryParameter` for my via points like

```
{
...,
via: new H.service.Url.MultiValueQueryParameter(['50.1234,8.7654', '51.2234,9.1123']);
}
```

I see in the URL params of my request this: `&via=%5Bobject%20Object%5D`

Someone an idea why this happens?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you use "via" parameter, you define a list of via waypoints. A via waypoint is not a native datatype recongnized by JavaScript, therefore, you will see in the URL params the word object refering to a particular data structure, in this case the via Waypoint composed mainly by Latitude, Longitude.
Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
But why am I getting an error from the here API when I use the via parameters? 


    "title": "Malformed request",
    "status": 400,
    "code": "E605001",
    "cause": "Error while parsing request:\n  Invalid value for parameter 'via' at '%5Bobject%20Object%5D'\n  Invalid waypoint at '[object Object]'\n  Invalid place at '[object Object]'\n  Invalid location at '[object Object]'",

Answer (score 0):

This took a while to figure out the actual issue with the malformed url params. I was dynamically loading the here maps service script on mount of a component. Accidentally this happened in some cases twice. In both cases `H`  was globally available and everything worked like expected. BUT when the script was loaded twice `H.service.Url.MultiValueQueryParameter` didn't return the correct params. It basically encoded them twice, or tried to.

The other side issue was that https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/heremaps is outdated and doesn't cover `MultiValueQueryParameter`. So I had to remove the types and use my own. Else I probably would have realized the issue earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.  This was very helpful. I was also trying to convert from V7 to V8.  I did not have any problems with the MultiValueQueryParameter being loaded twice, but I did see that the lat/long values were encoded multiple times in the resulting URL call to the v8 routes service.

Here's an example of how to call multiple "waypoints" with the new via option.
https://www.here.com/docs/bundle/maps-api-for-javascript-api-reference/page/H.service.RoutingService8.html

'via': new H.service.Url.MultiValueQueryParameter(['48.8664,2.3234', '48.8703,2.3499']),